# Geocoding with Google Maps without OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors - Trying with PHP-Solution

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

I hope you can help. Actually I´m trying to prevent the Google Maps-Api-Error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT". I want to solve it with PHP instead of using Javascript and playing around with Timeouts etc. For this I have replaced this line:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
```

in my script with this one:

```
var url_addr = encodeURIComponent(address);
$.getJSON('geocode.php?addr='+url_addr, function(data) { 
var results = data.results,
    status = data.status;
```

Additionally I have an PHP-Script for getting the geocode-coordinates:

```
$params = "address=" . urlencode($_GET{'addr'});
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&' . $params;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$status = json_decode($json)->status;

// check for over_query_limit status
while ($status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
sleep(0.2); // seconds
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$status = json_decode($json)->status;
}

header('application/json');
echo $json;
```

After running this I can see the called PHP-script in the debugger-console with the attached geocode-coordinates on the URL like /geocode.php?addr=432345...

Next in my JS-Script I want to check if the google.maps.GeocoderStatus is OK. So I call:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[1]) {
   console.log("Everything OK");
   }
  else {
   console.log("Geocode is not OK");
  }
```

But nothing happens. It seems that the status doesn´t arrive at the if-else. I played a bit around and tried to find out something with "Firebug", but I don´t find the answer.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you and regards,
Stefan

Comment: Why do you get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`? And why would server-side geocoding solve the problem? Maybe this could be an interesting reading: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Comment: I don´t know why I´m getting this error. I read a lot about this problem and noticed a lot of workarounds mentioning server-side geocoding could prevent it easier then doing it with js. I don´t know if it is really so, but I want to prove, try & learn :-)

Comment: Ok, I read the article. It doesnt make Sense with Server-sided geocoding... Thank you and regards, Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use your Google API Key in your PHP.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$params."&key=".$key."&sensor=false
```

$key = your Google API Key

It will help you prevent the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors.